# Can the `DeviceCheck` API generate a token when there is no internet connection?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, devicecheck

Can the DeviceCheck API generate a token when the device is offline?

```
if DCDevice.curDevice.isSupported {
    DCDevice.current.generateToken(completionHandler: { (data, error) in
        if let tokenData = data {
            print("Received token \(tokenData)")
        }
        else {
            print("Hit error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You can get device token in offline mode too. Device tokens can change after updating the operating system, and always change when a device's data and settings are erased.

Answer (score 1):

Device token can be received in offline mode too.

> Device tokens can change after updating the operating system, and
>   always change when a device's data and settings are erased

Answer (score 0):

The key can be generated offline by making use of `generatekey` API. However, while calling `attestkey` API to get the `attestationObject`, it will make a call to Apple's servers hence attestation will fail if tried in offline mode.

Some side notes to ensure the quality design of this solution -

1. While making attestkey API call, it can take considerable time (even upto 4 seconds at times).
2. Apple wants these calls to be made only when really
   needed and in a sensible way. In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/accessing_and_modifying_per_device_data), it is
   mentioned HTTP error 429 will be thrown for too many requests. There
   is no information about a maximum number of requests per min/hour,
   unfortunately.